# (Android) OutOfMemoryError thrown while trying to throw OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, android

So I'm creating an Android app and this code is what throws *"Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: OutOfMemoryError thrown while trying to throw OutOfMemoryError; no stack trace available"* error:

```
public ArrayList<Double> statModa(ArrayList<Double> statRed, ArrayList<Double> uniqueRed) {
    ArrayList<Double> result = new ArrayList<>();
    int maxFreqIndex = 0;
    int maxFreq = Collections.frequency(statRed, uniqueRed.get(0));
    for (int i=1; i < statRed.size(); i++){
        int currentFreq = Collections.frequency(statRed, statRed.get(i));
        if ((currentFreq >  maxFreq) || (currentFreq == maxFreq && statRed.get(i) == statRed.get(maxFreqIndex))) {
            maxFreqIndex = i;
            maxFreq = currentFreq;
        }
    }

    if (maxFreq == statRed.size() / uniqueRed.size())
        return result;

    if (maxFreqIndex == statRed.size()-1){
        result.add(statRed.get(maxFreqIndex));
        return result;
    }

    for (int i=maxFreqIndex+1; i < statRed.size(); i++){
        int currentFreq = Collections.frequency(statRed, statRed.get(i));
        if (currentFreq != maxFreq) {
            result.add(statRed.get(maxFreqIndex));
            int tempIndex = maxFreqIndexFinder(statRed, i, maxFreq);
            if (tempIndex == maxFreqIndex) {
                break;
            } else {
                i = tempIndex;
                maxFreqIndex = tempIndex;
            }
        } else {
            double temp = statRed.get(maxFreqIndex);
            int tempTimes = 1;
            for (int j=1; i + currentFreq*j - 1 < statRed.size(); j++){
                if (currentFreq == Collections.frequency(statRed, statRed.get(i + currentFreq*j - 1))) {
                    temp += statRed.get(i + currentFreq * j - 1);
                    tempTimes++;
                    maxFreqIndex = i + currentFreq * j - 1;
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
            result.add(temp/(double)tempTimes);
            i = maxFreqIndex;
        }
    }

    return result;
}

public int maxFreqIndexFinder(ArrayList<Double> statRed, int startingIndex, int maxFreq){
    int resultIndex = startingIndex - 1;
    int count = 0;
    double lastFreqValue = 0;
    for (int i = startingIndex; i < statRed.size(); i++){
        int currentFreq = Collections.frequency(statRed, statRed.get(i));
        if (currentFreq == maxFreq) {
            count++;
            if (count == 1) {
                resultIndex = i;
                lastFreqValue = statRed.get(i);
            } else {
                if (lastFreqValue == statRed.get(i)) {
                    resultIndex = i;
                    lastFreqValue = statRed.get(i);
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return resultIndex;
}
```

I'm not quite sure what exactly causes the error. I suspect a infinite loop, but I couldn't find it, so I'm asking here. Also before throwing the error it continuously allocates memory.

Here's the console log (if needed): [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/rux3r0dg)

**Additional info:**

The function **statModa** is ran when a button is clicked.

Red means line.

The values I ran the app with and got an error are as follows:

*ArrayList* **statRed** has the values {0.1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5 5 5} and

*ArrayList* **uniqueRed** has the values {0.1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}.

Also these are **not** the only values that give me this error. If this **(maxFreq == statRed.size() / uniqueRed.size())** is true then there is no error, if not then I get the error.

**P.S.** I saw another question with the same error, there was only one Answer which was to enable largeHeap, but it didn't work for me.

Comment: `statRed has the values {0.1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5 5 5}`: should the 5 5 5 have commas between them?

Comment: Please use a debugger to narrow down the issue

Comment: your code looks pretty ugly and overly complicated, but I would suggest trying to remove parts of it, looks like infinite loop or something similar...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The OOm is because of the line `i = maxFreqIndex;`, as for the given input `maxFreqIndex` is 8 and doesn't change, so you get infinite loop at `for (int i=maxFreqIndex+1; i < statRed.size(); i++)`